# 16.04: How to both write and run bash shell-script from cloud-init?

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, openstack, cloud-init

I am writing the following cloud-init file to be executed when a VM is deployed in OpenStack:

```
#cloud-config
password: passwword
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True

write_files:
-   content: |
        This is the write_files and should be line 1 of 2

    path: /home/ubuntu/file.txt

-   content: |
        echo "This is the runcmd and should be line 3 of 3" >> /home/ubuntu/file.txt

    owner: root:root
    permissions: '755'
    path: /home/ubuntu/bin/test

runcmd:
  - echo "This is the runcmd and should be line 2 of 2" >> /home/ubuntu/file.txt
  - test
```

After the VM starts, the output of `cat file.txt` is :

```
This is the write_files and should be line 1 of 2
This is the runcmd and should be line 2 of 2
```

So, the last line of the `cloud-init` is not executed which run a shell-script called `test` which writes to `file.txt` ..

what am I doing wrong ?!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `/home/ubuntu/bin/` isn't in the PATH.
Try specifying the absolute path `/home/ubuntu/bin/test` in the `runcmd`